# Case Expressions in Oracle SQL (Pentaho Report Designer)

Tags: sql, oracle, pentaho-report-designer

I need to pull ages of clients and have results broken down into categories (18-21, 22-35, 36-50, etc).

Using Pentaho Report Designer which is Oracle based.

I can pull a count of specific ages, but want the count to reflect the age ranges, not a single age.  Attempting to complete this through a case statement but continually get errors.

Minimal SQL exposure, new to Pentaho/Oracle, new to this website.

--SQL for Age and Count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"
FROM "CLIENT_TABLE"
GROUP BY "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"
ORDER BY "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"
```

--This is my CASE expression.

```
CASE
    WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
    WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" > 18 AND <= 21 THEN '19 - 21'
    WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" > 21 AND <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
END AS Age
```

I have placed the CASE expression in both the SELECT and WHERE clauses, but continually get these two error messages... "FROM keyword not found where expects" & "Missing expression".

Updated code produces error, "not a Group By Expression."

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
      (CASE
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 21 THEN '18 - 21'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 50 THEN '36 - 50'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 64 THEN '51 - 64'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" >= 65 THEN '65+'
       END) AS AgeRange
FROM "CLIENT_TABLE"
GROUP BY (CASE
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 21 THEN '18 - 21'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 50 THEN '36 - 50'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 64 THEN '51 - 64'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" >= 65 THEN '65+'
       END)
ORDER BY "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"
```

Comment: `case` **expression** not "statement".  Also, do you have something against 18-year olds?

Comment: update your question and showt the sql code you are really using  ..  not just a part

Comment: If you have no data in one of the ranges, e.g. nobody over 64, do you expect to not see that range at all, or to see a count of zero for that range?

Comment: Ideally, a '0' for any range that returns no data.  Also, I should have an ELSE in the CASE for null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify this:

```
SELECT AGERANGE, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 21 THEN '18 - 21'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 50 THEN '36 - 50'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 64 THEN '51 - 64'
        WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" >= 65 THEN '65+'
       END) AS AgeRange
FROM "CLIENT_TABLE")
GROUP BY AGERANGE
ORDER BY CASE AGERANGE
WHEN 'Under 18' THEN 1 
WHEN '18 - 21' THEN 2
WHEN '22 - 35' THEN 3
WHEN '36 - 50' THEN 4
WHEN '51 - 64' THEN 5
WHEN '65+' THEN 6 
ELSE 7 END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you Tejash!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the help and guidance.

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue then please accept it so that it will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       (CASE WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
             WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 21 THEN '19 - 21'
             WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
        END) AS Age
FROM "CLIENT_TABLE"
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
               WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 21 THEN '19 - 21'
               WHEN "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= 35 THEN '22 - 35'
           END)
ORDER BY "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"
```

Notes:

- In Oracle, you need to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`.
- I simplified the logic for the conditions in the `case` expression.  The conditions are evaluated in order.
- In doing so, the 18-year olds are included -- now in the `'19 - 21'` group.  Including them somewhere seems more right than putting them in the `NULL` group.

Comment: Does this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Your 'updated code', based on @Gordon's answer, gets "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" because you're trying to order by `"CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"` - and that column is not in the `GROUP BY` clause. You probably want:

```
ORDER BY MIN("CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE")
```

However, this will only show you ranges which have matching data. If you want to see all ranges, including zero counts, you can generate the ranges as an inline view or CTE and outer join to your real data, e.g.:

```
WITH "RANGES" ("MIN_AGE", "MAX_AGE", "LABEL") AS (
  SELECT 0, 17, 'Under 18' FROM "DUAL"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 18, 21, '18 - 21' FROM "DUAL"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 22, 35, '22 - 35' FROM "DUAL"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 36, 50, '36 - 50' FROM "DUAL"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 51, 64, '51 - 64' FROM "DUAL"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 65, NULL, '65+' FROM "DUAL"
)
SELECT COUNT("CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE"),
       "RANGES"."LABEL" AS AgeRange
FROM "RANGES"
LEFT JOIN "CLIENT_TABLE"
ON "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" >= "RANGES"."MIN_AGE"
AND ("RANGES"."MAX_AGE" IS NULL OR "CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE" <= "RANGES"."MAX_AGE")
GROUP BY "RANGES"."MIN_AGE", "RANGES"."LABEL"
ORDER BY "RANGES"."MIN_AGE"
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fc75c9e10648f3d9e34321ee98edcd6)

You could generate the labels from the min/max age, or even just from a min age (using lead to find the max), and there are other variations you can explore.

(I've assumed you have uppercase and quoted identifiers for a reason, possibly a requirement of your reporting tool - I know some odd things do need them; but from Oracle's point of view the double-quotes aren't needed, and personally I find lowercase or mixed code (maybe keywords uppercase) easier to read. You might want to use table aliases as well.)

---

> I should have an ELSE in the CASE for null values.

`COUNT()` ignores nulls, so `COUNT("CLIENT_TABLE"."AGE")` will return zero if those are null. You would need to count any not-null column in the table instead; and would need another dummy row in the `RANGES` CTE, and modified logic to include the rows with no age set; e.g.:

```
with ranges (min_age, max_age, label) as (
  select 0, 17, 'Under 18' from dual
  union all
  select 18, 21, '18 - 21' from dual
  union all
  select 22, 35, '22 - 35' from dual
  union all
  select 36, 50, '36 - 50' from dual
  union all
  select 51, 64, '51 - 64' from dual
  union all
  select 65, null, '65+' from dual
  union all
  select null, null, 'Unknown' from dual
)
select count(client_table.id), -- count any not-null column from this table
       ranges.label as agerange
from ranges
left join client_table
on ((ranges.min_age is null and client_table.age is null)
  or client_table.age >= ranges.min_age)
and (ranges.max_age is null or client_table.age <= ranges.max_age)
group by ranges.min_age, ranges.label
order by ranges.min_age
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=011efec1fc85a7c2e97a62a682d7dc64)